# Google Colab + Pytorch: RuntimeError: No CUDA GPUs are available

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, google-colaboratory

**Screenshot of error:**

[image: screenshot of error]

Hello, I am trying to run [this Pytorch application](https://github.com/espectre/Kaggle-Dogs_vs_Cats_PyTorch), which is a CNN for classifying dog and cat pics.

I am using Google Colab for the GPU, but for some reason, I get `RuntimeError: No CUDA GPUs are available`. This is weird because I specifically both enabled the GPU in Colab settings, then tested if it was available with `torch.cuda.is_available()`, which returned true.

The weirdest thing is that this error doesn't appear until about 1.5 minutes after I run the code. You would think that if it couldn't detect the GPU, it would notify me sooner.

I've had no problems using the Colab GPU when running other Pytorch applications using the exact same notebook. I can only imagine it's a problem with this specific code, but the returned error is so bizarre that I had to ask on StackOverflow to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try again, this is usually a transient issue when there are no Cuda GPUs available

Answer (score -1):

Recently I had a similar problem, where Cobal print(torch.cuda.is_available()) was True, but print(torch.cuda.is_available()) was False on a specific project. Both of our projects have this code similar to os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]. I can use this code comment and find that the GPU can be used.

-------My English is poor, I use Google Translate

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31401568)